# Hausdorffness inheritance in topological groups

Tags: topological-groups, counterexamples

Suppose $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal S$ are two compatible Hausdorff topologies on a group $G$ and $\mathcal R$ is a maximum compatible topology on $G$ with $\mathcal R \subseteq \mathcal T\cap \mathcal S$.

Is $(G,\mathcal R)$ Hausdorff?

Comment: Is there some reason for the strange spelling in the title? "I am moft ferioufly difpleafed".

Comment: @ToddTrimble: there'ff ffome.

Comment: What does it mean for two topologies to be compatible? (That for both topologies $G$ is a topological group?)

Comment: Is there some reason for the strange spelling in the title? “I om most seriously displeosed”.

Comment: Topolgies are compatible with the group, making it a topological group.

Comment: Just to archive an answer:  Let $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal S$ be any two different compact Hausdorff compatible topologies. Since compact groups are minimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the answer is no. Basically, the $p$-adic and Archimedean topologies on $\mathbb{Q}$ are incompatible enough that the maximal compatible topology contained in both of them is indiscrete. Here is an outline of the proof (I'm heading to bed so I haven't filled in the details):

$\bullet$ Any subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is open for both topologies must be dense for both topologies. Therefore, all elements of $\mathcal{R}$ are dense.

$\bullet$ If $\mathcal{R}$ is compatible with the group structure, the complement of the antidiagonal in $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ must be open. Since this complement contains e.g. $(1,1)$, it must contain a set of the form $U\times U$ for some $U\in \mathcal{R}$.

$\bullet$ This is impossible since $U\cap U^{-1}\neq \emptyset$ by density of $U$.

Comment: What I remember from my notes on uniform spaces, is that $p$-adic uniformity on $\Bbb Q$ is the uniformity generated by $\{W_n\mid n\in \Bbb N \}$ where $W_n=\{(r,s)\in \Bbb Q^2\mid p^n|r-s\}$. Please give me definitions of Archimedean and $p$-adic topologies on $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I think he meant to write "euclidean" instead of "archimedean".

Comment: Yes, by archimedean I meant the restriction of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. For the definition of the $p$-adic topology, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This answer is completely wrong. Please ignore it, and see Kevin's answer.

---

A $T_{0}$-topological group $G$ is Hausdorff ($T_{2}$). Recall that $T_{0}$ means that for all $x,y \in G$, there is an open subset $U$ such that $x \in U, y \notin U$ or $y \in U, x \notin U$.

Consequently (by homogeneity), a topological group is Hausdorff if and only if the one element subgroup of the unit element is closed.

Thus, for your question it suffices to show that $\{1\} \subset G$ is closed for the $\mathcal{R}$-topology. This is clear if we show that $\mathcal{R} = \mathcal{T} \cap \mathcal{S}$. Let $U$ be an open subset for $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{S}$. For every element $g \in G$, the set $gU$ is open for $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{S}$, because both were compatible. For the same reason $U^{-1}$ is open for both $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{S}$. Hence $\mathcal{R} = \mathcal{T} \cap \mathcal{S}$ is compatible.

Consequently $U = G - \{1\}$ is an open subset for $\mathcal{R}$, and hence $(G,\mathcal{R})$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: For showing compatibility, why is it enough to show that $gU$ is open for all $g$ and $U^{-1}$ is open? For instance, if I take an abstract infinite group and put the cofinite topology on it, then both of those conditions are satsified, but the cofinite topology is not compatible.

Comment: Let me be *seriously displeosed* too! There are examples which show the intersection of two compatible topologies is not necessarily compatible. you have proved inverse, and left (right) multiplication are continuous. While continuity of the 2-variable multiplication function needs a serious proof.

Comment: Hmm, you are very right! I don't know what made me think this is enough. Excuse my stupidity.

Comment: You're answer is completely wrong, but if you add local compactness to $\mathcal R$, It may be completely correct according to a theorem due to Ellis. Good point for me, why I +1.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus — That is very generous. Thank you.